# How can I configure TeamViewer so that the monitor that is being viewed corresponds to the most recently opened window?

Tags: windows, multiple-monitors, teamviewer, screen-sharing

I use TeamViewer to access a computer running Microsoft Windows 10. The computer has multiple monitors attached to it. The TeamViewer bar has a button going to switch which monitor is being viewed:

[image]

How can I configure TeamViewer so that the monitor that is being viewed automatically corresponds to the most recently opened window?

Comment: Do you mean to say that it should remember the last-used monitor?

Comment: @harrymc I meant: if a window becomes active, e.g. by starting a program or clicking on one of the windows in the taskbar, then TeamViewer should display whichever monitor contains the newly active window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TeamViewer cannot do that. Multi-monitor options are only:

- Show all monitor screens at the same time in a single window
- Display monitors as individual tabs
- Display monitors as individual windows
- Ability to "tear off" a tab and move elsewhere

And that is the sum total of what you can do.